# Why "das Schwert im Meer versenken", not "ins Meer", despite a movement implied?

Tags: grammatical-case

> den Kopf in **ein** Buch versenken +++ {accusative}
>
> sich in **ihre** Arbeit versenken +++ {accusative}

On the other hand:

> das Schwert **im** Meer versenken +++ {dative}

Although these three examples share the same construction and the movement/action of sinking/throwing X into Y is implied, the last one alone requires the dative case for some reason.

I wonder why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Versenken** has two meanings.

One meaning is "to put away by sinking" and asks for a location. It goes only with dative.

> Der Sturm versenkte die Flotte im Hafen.

*The storm sunk the fleet in the harbour.*

> Mit diesem Eigentor hat der HSV sich selbst im Tabellenkeller versenkt.

*By that own goal the HSV had sunk itself at the bottom of the league.*

The other meaning is "to dive in/into" and that one can go both with a location or a direction.

> Er versenkte den Kopf in einem Buch.
>
> Er versenkte den Kopf in ein Buch.

You can use either of these. The accusative case puts more emphasis on the action.

Comment: I consider it at least questionable whether these are two meanings. I am indeed having a hard time imagining an accusative example in the first described case, but I think that is mainly due to the issue that whatever the ships are sinking in is larger than the ships, therefore there is no movement *into* a new location. Try the not too straightforward "Der Sturm versenkte die Flotte in den bereits bestehenden Schiffsfriedhof auf dem Grund des Hafens.", and you will notice that I have used accusative along with the first alleged meaning. Come to think of it, your second example that ...

Comment: ... "goes only with dative" actually uses "sich selbst" as an accusative object.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: No, "versenkte die Flotte in den" is wrong. It's always in de**m**. Neither is the accusative object asked in my second example but the accusative usage of the prepositional object introduced by **in**.

Comment: But "versenkte die Flotte im Schiffsfriedhof" makes no sense. The fleet only enters the ship graveyard upon sinking to the ground. Thus, it *must* be "versenkte die Flotte in den Schiffsfriedhof".

Comment: I know *nobody*, really **no one** but you, who ever uses *versenken* in that sense with a direction.

Comment: ["versenkte den Leichnam in die Schlei"](https://de.wikisource.org/wiki/Die_Abelssage); ["versenkte den Strafstoß in die linke Torecke"](http://www.marbacher-zeitung.de/inhalt.freiberg-fussball-spaeter-rueckschlag-im-spitzenspiel.75910743-80ee-4cc2-bc76-ea2eac6c7cc5.html); ["trug die Urne (...), versenkte sie in das Loch"](http://www.nnz-online.de/news/news_lang.php?ArtNr=163765); ... no, it's certainly not just me.